# Sound not dissapating

Tags: c#, audio, unity-game-engine, spatial

I'am making a Unity game for the oculus, and while working on the sound I noticed that the Sound is equally loud from any given distance from the campfire, so if you're right on top of it it'll be as loud as being 500 meters away from the campfire.

```
 1. Play on Awake - on
 2. Loop - on
 3. Priority - 128
 4. Volume - 0.021
 5. Pitch - 1
 6. Stereo Pan - 0
 7. Spatial Blend - 1
 8. Reverb Zone Mix - 1
 9. Doppler Level - 0
 10. Spread - 0
 11. Volume Rolloff - Logarithmic Rolloff
 12. Min Distance - 0.5
 13. Max Distance - 2.5
```

I've tried the following things:

Rebuilding the object, changing min & max distance, using a different sound, toggling different settings, I've tried each Volume Rolloff, I've tried different Spread settings & different Doppler Levels.

Does anyone know how to fix this? The Spatial Blend should fix my problem, but it doesn't.

Comment: Where are your OSP or ONSP audio source settings? [developers.ocullus audiosdk](https://developer.oculus.com/documentation/audiosdk/latest/concepts/ospnative-unity-req-setup/)

Comment: They're set to:

Global Volume - 1
Volume Rolloff scale - 1
Doppler Factor - 1
Default Speaker Mode - Stereo
System Sample Rate - 1
DSP Buffersize - Best Latency
Max Virtual Voices - 512
Max Real Voices - 32
Spatializer Plugin - OculusSpatializer

Comment: Those are your audio manager settings, I would like to know the audio source settings [more relevant image](https://gyazo.com/3000303bce75504cc94014b3b17e0468)

Comment: I've described the audio source settings in my original post

Comment: OSP or ONSP audio source settings

Comment: They're - Enable Spatialization - on, Disable reflections - off, Gain - 0, INVERSE SQUARE ANNETATIONS - off, Fall off range - near - 1, far - 10

Comment: Which audio command do you use? oneshot, playclipatpoint etc.  Is your audio file set to a 3d sound? (edit the relevant data, including the info from previous comments into your question, this will provide others a more complete oversight as well)

Comment: I don't use a command, I loop it while im in the scene